# Can't run 60hz on external display with MacBook Pro 15 2019

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I just bought **Baseus Enjoy series Type-C to HDMI*2+PD HD intelligent HUB adapter**
and it works only on 30hz port on my Samsung  u28e590ds monitor. I use MacBook Pro 15 2019. If I plug into 60hz port it recognized by MacBook but screen is black. I tried different cables - all the same. Is issue with the adapter?

Comment: Are you only connecting 1 external monitor? Are you running the power through the adapter as well?

Comment: Yes, it's one display. I tried to plug the adapter as well.

Comment: From this customer comment on the Samsung [product description page](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/samsung-uhd-28-monitor-with-high-glossy-black-finish-lu28e590ds-za/) for the monitor: `Be sure to use a DisplayPort 1.2 connection for full 4K at 60Hz (HDMI only does 30Hz).` and `... this monitor is great as long as you only use the DP cable. The HDMI ports do not offer 4k at 60HZ.`

Answer (score 1):

Just bought USB type-c to DP adapter and it works fine. Thanks!